# Multi column explode in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

This is my excel input

[image]

This is my expected output

I am expecting all possible combinations for all comma seperated values of each columns into separate rows

[image]

Current work

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
   if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
       df = df.append(pd.read_excel('downloads/' + file), ignore_index=True) 
df.head() 
df.to_excel(r'downloads/merged.xlsx')

df.type_c = df.type_c.str.split(',')
df1 = df.explode('type_c') 

df1.language_c = df1.language_c.str.split(',')
df1.explode('language_c')
```

Here I am exploding multiple columns, Can I get this done in single command, where it can do this exploding for all columns without specifying? OR should it run through a loop for all columns which has ',' in it?

Comment: related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe-into-multiple-rows/53218939#53218939)

Answer (score 1):

Can just make it a definition.

```
def explodePandas(files):
    global df, df1 # If needed
    for file in files:
        if file.endswitch('.xlsx'):
            df = df.append(pd.read_excel('downloads/' + file), ignore_index = True)
    df.head()

    df.to_excel(r'downloads/merged.xlsx')

    df.type_c = df.type_c.str.split(',')
    df1 = df.explode('type_c') 

    df1.language_c = df1.language_c.str.split(',')
    df1.explode('language_c')

explodePandas()
```

Comment: i dont want to specify every column name, I might have 20 other columns like this but would like explode function on it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this approach could assist you:

#### Generating working dataframe

- Code

  ```markdown
  dfx = pd.DataFrame(
      data={
          'scope': ['internal'],
          'type_c': ['bmm, pitcher'],
          'subtype_c': ['ad experiment'],
          'language_c': ['en, esp'],
      }
  )
  ```
- Result

  ```markdown
  dfx

      scope       type_c          subtype_c       language_c
  0   internal    bmm, pitcher    ad experiment   en, esp
  ```

#### Exploding rows based on entries that contain a comma

- Code

  ```markdown
  ## Iterable of all column names in dataframe
  cols = dfx.columns

  ## Looping through every column to split and make cross join
  for col in cols:

      ## Exploding a column into various columns using ',' as a separator
      dfx2 = dfx[col].str.split(pat=',', expand=True).T

      ## Renaming the obtained exploded result to match the original column name
      dfx2.rename(columns={0: col}, inplace=True)

      ## Dropping the processed column from the original dataframe
      dfx.drop(col, axis=1, inplace=True)

      ## Conducting a cross join between the 'exploded column' and the original dataframe
      dfx = pd.merge(
          left=dfx,
          right=dfx2,
          how='cross',
      )

  ## Ensuring that you only keep the columns from the original list
  ### Note: this is a 'hard-coded' solution to deal with the additional columns obtained with the cross join
  dfx = dfx.loc[:, cols].copy()
  ```
- Result

  ```markdown
  dfx

      scope   type_c          subtype_c       language_c
  0   internal    bmm         ad experiment   en
  1   internal    bmm         ad experiment   esp
  2   internal    pitcher     ad experiment   en
  3   internal    pitcher     ad experiment   esp
  ```

Hope this approach helps you!